# How to display images from Frirebase Storage in StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage, stream-builder

I'm trying to display images from `FirebaseStorage` in `StreamBuilder` when user add them after they have been saved in FirebaseStorage

**Try #1**

It works but only the last added image is shown as stream and I would like to display all the images added.
I guess this try is the better way but I can't add `ListView.builder` because `TaskSnapshot` is one data and not a list of data like ListResult that's probably why I can't diplay all images and only the last one.

Widget:

```
Widget loadingImage(UploadTask uploadTask) => StreamBuilder<TaskSnapshot>(
      stream: uploadTask.snapshotEvents,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasData) {
          final snap = snapshot.data;
          final photoName = snap!.metadata!.name;
          final photoType = snap.metadata!.contentType;
          final photo = snapshot.data!.ref.getDownloadURL();

          return StreamBuilder(
              stream: photo.asStream(),
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
                final image = snapshot.data;
                print("Image: $image");

                return Row(
                  children: [
                    Image.network(
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      width: 100,
                      height: 100,
                      image!,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 20,),
                    Text(
                      photoName,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 20,),
                    Text(
                      photoType!,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                );
              }
          );
        }
        return Container();
      },
  );
```

**Try #2**

It displays images but not as stream if one is added it's not shown if a second one is added the first one will be displayed etc

DocumentViewModel:

```
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //----------------------------- Upload instructor document list --------------
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------

  static Stream<ListResult>? uploadFileList(String uid) {
    try {
      final result = FirebaseStorage.instance
              .ref("instructorDocuments/")
              .child("$uid/")
              .listAll();

      return result.asStream();
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Widget:

```
Widget loadingImage(UploadTask uploadTask) => StreamBuilder<ListResult>(
      stream: DocumentViewModel.uploadFileList(user!.uid),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasData) {
          final snap = snapshot.data;

          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snap!.items.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final photoName = snap.items[index].name;
                final photoType = snap.items[index].getMetadata();
                final photo = snap.items[index].getDownloadURL();

                return StreamBuilder<FullMetadata>(
                    stream: photoType.asStream(),
                    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<FullMetadata> snapshot) {
                      if(snapshot.hasData) {
                        final type = snapshot.data!.contentType;

                        return StreamBuilder(
                            stream: photo.asStream(),
                            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
                              if(snapshot.hasData) {
                                final image = snapshot.data;

                                return Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Image.network(
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                      width: 100,
                                      height: 100,
                                      image!,
                                    ),
                                    const SizedBox(width: 20,),
                                    Text(
                                      photoName,
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 18,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    const SizedBox(width: 20,),
                                    Text(
                                      type!,
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 18,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                );
                              }
                              return Container();
                            },
                        );
                      }
                      return Container();
                    }
                );
              },
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          );
        }
        if(!snapshot.hasData) {
          return const Loader();
        }
        if(snapshot.hasError) {
          return Utils.showErrorMessage(snapshot.hasError.toString());
        }
        else {
          return Container();
        }
      }
  );
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try this without streambuilder for getting images from firebase

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BlogView extends StatefulWidget {
  const BlogView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BlogView> createState() => _BlogViewState();
}
var im;
var allimgList = [];
class _BlogViewState extends State<BlogView> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    getData();
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
    });
  }
  void getData() async {
    allimgList=[];
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Names')
        .snapshots()
        .forEach((event) {
          var n=event.docs.length;
          print(event.docs.length);
      for (int i = 0; i <n; i++) {
        im = event.docs[i]['Images'];
        var nn=event.docs[i]['Images'].length;
        for(int j=0;j<nn;j++){
          allimgList.add(im[j]);
          setState(() {});
        }
        if(i==n)break;
      }
      print("=========>"  + allimgList.toString());
    });
      setState(() {
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // print("================lllllllll =>" + allimgList.toString());
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Blog"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: allimgList.length == 0 ?
               Container(
                  height: 500,
                  width: 300,
                  child: Center(child: Text("No Image Added Yet")),
                ):Container(

            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
            child: GridView.builder(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                    maxCrossAxisExtent: 150,
                    childAspectRatio: 4 / 4,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 20),
                itemCount: allimgList.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, index) {
                  return Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                    child: Image.network(
                      allimgList[index],
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                  );
                }),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: My images are in `Firebase Storage` not in Firestore but it seems I have to create a collection in Firestore to get the full list

Comment: you should upload the image in firestore then get the url then store the  url in firebase then you can use it